# Google Sheet script to hide rows if date in column older than a week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like a script that hides rows if the date in column F is older than a week. I thought I found one but it hid the headers of the columns (row 2) as well which is no use.

I don't want it to hide empty rows as they will be continuously updated.

Many thanks.

Comment: What code have you tried? Please edit your question to include your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

This function checks each cell in a column to insure it is a date and then it will hide rows when it detects a date older that 7 days.  Of course, you can change it so that the number of days is an argument if you like. It requires you to select a column which is currently defaulted to 'A'.  I included the menu just to make it simpler for you to test.

```
 function onOpen()
    {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('My Tools')
            .addItem('Hide Rows','hideRowsDate')
            .addToUi();
    }
    
    function hideRowsDate(column)
    {
      var column = (typeof(column) !== 'undefined') ? column : 'A';
      var day = 86400000;
      var today = new Date().getTime();
      var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(column + ':' + column);
      var rngA = rng.getValues();
      for(var i = 0; i < rngA.length ;i++)
      {
        if(isDate(rngA[i][0]) && (((today - new Date(rngA[i][0]).getTime())/day) > 7 ))
        {
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(i + 1);
        }
      
      }
    }
    
    function isDate (x)  
    { 
      return (null != x) && !isNaN(x) && ("undefined" !== typeof x.getDate); 
    }
```