# Google Sheet script to hide columns by date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm essentially trying to do exactly what was done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296254/google-sheet-script-to-hide-rows-if-date-in-column-older-than-a-week?newreg=d42a9902b23a4974a75d1196d1c799cf), but with columns instead of rows. When I run the script there as is, it works fine. But just switching all references to columns to rows (and vice versa) isn't working for me, for some reason, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

For reference, this is what I have:

```js
function onOpen()
    {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('My Tools')
            .addItem('Hide Columns','hideColumnsDate')
            .addToUi();
    }

    function hideColumnsDate(row)
    {
      var row = (typeof(row) !== 'undefined') ? row : '1';
      var day = 86400000;
      var today = new Date().getTime();
      var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row + ':' + row);
      var rngA = rng.getValues();
      for(var i = 0; i < rngA.length ;i++)
      {
        if(isDate(rngA[i][0]) && (((today - new Date(rngA[i][0]).getTime())/day) > 7 ))
        {
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(i + 1);
        }

      }
    }

    function isDate (x)  
    { 
      return (null != x) && !isNaN(x) && ("undefined" !== typeof x.getDate); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script is modified, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several modifications.

#### Modification points:

- In your situation, the values retrieved from the range of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row + ':' + row)` is `[[column1, column2, column3,,,]]`.

  - In this case, the length of the for loop is `rngA[0].length`.
  - In order to retrieve the values of the columns, please modify `rngA[i][0]` to `rngA[0][i]`.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rngA.length ;i++)
{
  if(isDate(rngA[i][0]) && (((today - new Date(rngA[i][0]).getTime())/day) > 7 ))
```

To:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rngA[0].length ;i++)
{
  if(isDate(rngA[0][i]) && (((today - new Date(rngA[0][i]).getTime())/day) > 7 ))
```

#### Note:

- In your case, as other pattern, you can also use the following modification.

  - Modify `var rngA = rng.getValues();` to `var rngA = rng.getValues()[0];`, and modify `rngA[i][0]` to `rngA[i]`.
- In above modified script, all rows of a column are checked. If you want to check the specific columns, please tell me.

#### Reference:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @janine610 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideColumnsDate(row) {
  var row=row||1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(row,1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues()[0];
  var today=new Date().valueOf();
  vA.forEach(function(e,i){
    var rowdate=new Date(e).valueOf();
    if(((today-rowdate)/86400000)>7) {
      sh.hideColumns(i+1);
    }
  }); 
}
```